# how to reduce noise in image

Tags: image, c#-4.0, image-processing

I need some help and maybe idea about my job.
in fact I want to do these:

1. doing edge detection on grayscale images
2. export just detected edges
3. save it in *.png format

Now I have a problem. you can see it in picture that i linked it.

pic 1 is base, pic 2 is edge detected image, and pic 3 is png format  but there is a problem in pic3. in fact after this line (c# code).

```
btmimg.MakeTransparent(Color.Empty);     
Image img = (Image)btmimg;
img.Save("1" + ".Png", ImageFormat.Png(;
```

I see noises around the detected edges .

[image: Example]

So anybody have any idea about this ? how  can I reduce these noises?

Is there other way that export detected edges and make new image?

Comment: Please explain why it's necessary to make all the empty (black?) pixels transparent before saving the image.

Comment: In fact i want to put on (or Combining) image3 on image1 . To see the changes

Comment: Then what you should do is invert the edge detection results (so the black parts appear white and vice versa) and put them in the alpha channel of a plain white PNG image. I'm afraid I don't know how to do this in C# but it shouldn't be hard to find out. Also, stop using JPEG compression. Part of the reason your "transparent" image is so noisy is because you're apparently applying edge detection to a JPEG image and enhancing all the compression artefacts. Use PNGs instead.

Comment: I did it. i combined image3 and image1 . but image3 has noise and result isn't suitable. Thanks for your solution i do work with png format.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your noise is in the black values.
Things might look as black, but not be 100% black.
So your edge detection filter sees that and includes the nearly black.
Maybe prefilter your data, so that any black valeu below a certain treshold is seen as black.

And you better not use image compression here, and specify the png not to compress either.